# While creating apk with Kivmob and its settings, Buildozer Gradle Fails

Tags: gradle, kivy, build.gradle, gradlew, buildozer

I have a problem in Buildozer that related with Gradlew. I have a free app so i used Kivmob library to show ads in it.Although the Kivmob's document is a little old but mainly it needs android.minapi,android.sdk, android.ndk, android.gradle_dependencies, android.meta_data, p4a.branch and android.permissions. When i want to create apk i get error.
If i only use android.api = 33 there is no problem
Could you please help me about this issue please?

**java -version**

```
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Some Important settings**

```
android.api = 33
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 33
android.ndk = 25b
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.4.0'
android.enable_androidx = True
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
p4a.branch = master
android.meta_data = 'com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID = ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713'
```

**If i comment them (above buildozer.specs lines), (out of android.api = 33) there are no problem. I get apk.**

**BUILDOZER SPECS:**

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3==3.11.7,kivy==2.3.0,aiohttp==3.9.3,aiosignal==1.3.1,attrs==23.2.0,beautifulsoup4==4.12.3,certifi==2024.2.2,charset-normalizer==3.3.2,docutils==0.20.1,frozenlist==1.4.1,idna==3.6,multidict==6.0.5,requests==2.31.0,soupsieve==2.5,Unidecode==1.3.8,urllib3==2.2.0,yarl==1.9.4,android,jnius,kivmob

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/images/loading.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/images/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.11.7

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.3.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 33

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 33

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 25b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class which extends PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk res directory.
# The option may be used in three ways, the value may contain one or zero ':'
# Some examples:
# 1) A file to add to resources, legal resource names contain ['a-z','0-9','_']
# android.add_resources = my_icons/all-inclusive.png:drawable/all_inclusive.png
# 2) A directory, here  'legal_icons' must contain resources of one kind
# android.add_resources = legal_icons:drawable
# 3) A directory, here 'legal_resources' must contain one or more directories, 
# each of a resource kind:  drawable, xml, etc...
# android.add_resources = legal_resources
#android.add_resources =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.4.0'

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
android.enable_androidx = True

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Copy these files to src/main/res/xml/ (used for example with intent-filters)
#android.res_xml = PATH_TO_FILE,

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (str) screenOrientation to set for the main activity.
# Valid values can be found at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element
#android.manifest.orientation = fullSensor

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) Skip byte compile for .py files
# android.no-byte-compile-python = False

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk or aar).
android.release_artifact = aab

# (str) The format used to package the app for debug mode (apk or aar).
android.debug_artifact = apk

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = develop

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =
```

**ERROR:**

```
footballpredictor has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor
[DEBUG]:   Remove directory and subdirectory src/main/assets
[DEBUG]:   Create directory src/main/assets
Compiling '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.py'...
Compiling '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/app/main.py'...

[DEBUG]:   Remove directory and subdirectory /tmp/p4a-extra-env-5a5i1lux
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 35.0.0-rc1
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew clean assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Where:
[DEBUG]:    Build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle' line: 75
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    Could not compile build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle'.
[DEBUG]:    > startup failed:
[DEBUG]:      build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle': 75: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 75, column 14.
[DEBUG]:         dependencies {
[DEBUG]:                      ^
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:      1 error
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[DEBUG]:    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD FAILED in 540ms
[DEBUG]:    

Exception in thread background thread for pid 463451:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/seo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/seo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/seo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/seo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc

sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/gradlew clean assembleDebug



  STDOUT:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle' line: 75

* What went wrong:

Could not compile build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle'.

> startup failed:

  build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle': 75: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 75, column 14.

     dependencies {

                  ^

  

  1 error



* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 540ms

  STDERR:

[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 27):

    * What went wrong:  

Could not compile build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle'.  

> startup failed:   

  build file '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/build.gradle': 75: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 75, column 14.  

     dependencies { 

                  ^ 

    

  1 error       

* Try:  
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
> Run with --scan to get full insights. 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  
BUILD FAILED in 540ms   

[INFO]:    STDERR:  

[INFO]:    ENV:
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
export SESSION_MANAGER='local/seo:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2812,unix/seo:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2812'
export QT_ACCESSIBILITY='1'
export COLORTERM='truecolor'
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS='/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
export SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER='gnome-keyring'
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX='gnome-'
export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID='this-is-deprecated'
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE='ubuntu'
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK='/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
export XMODIFIERS='@im=ibus'
export DESKTOP_SESSION='ubuntu'
export GTK_MODULES='gail:atk-bridge'
export DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE='session'
export PWD='/home/seo/Desktop/APP'
export LOGNAME='seo'
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP='ubuntu'

export XDG_SESSION_TYPE='wayland'
export SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID='2812'
export XAUTHORITY='/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.OD6BJ2'
export HOME='/home/seo'
export USERNAME='seo'
export IM_CONFIG_PHASE='1'
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'

export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'

export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP='ubuntu:GNOME'
export VTE_VERSION='6800'
export WAYLAND_DISPLAY='wayland-0'
export GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN='/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/106a7e88_f4e2_4f71_a0af_df2f59eb382d'
export GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY=':1'
export LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
export XDG_SESSION_CLASS='user'
export TERM='xterm-256color'
export LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
export USER='seo'
export GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=':1.148'
export DISPLAY=':0'
export SHLVL='1'
export QT_IM_MODULE='ibus'
export DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS='unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=3f19386d594c848fbecbb08b65d31412'
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/run/user/1000'
export XDG_DATA_DIRS='/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
export PATH='/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/seo/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/seo/.local/bin/'
export GDMSESSION='ubuntu'
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=3f19386d594c848fbecbb08b65d31412'
export _='/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
export PACKAGES_PATH='/home/seo/.buildozer/android/packages'
export ANDROIDSDK='/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
export ANDROIDNDK='/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
export ANDROIDAPI='33'
export ANDROIDMINAPI='21'
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME='/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
export ANDROID_HOME='/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor && /home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/gradlew clean assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/footballpredictor/gradlew failed!
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'apk', '--bootstrap', 'sdl2', '--dist_name', 'footballpredictor', '--name', 'Football Predictor', '--version', '2.5', '--package', 'org.mecra.footballpredictor', '--minsdk', '21', '--ndk-api', '21', '--private', '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/app', '--permission', 'INTERNET', '--permission', 'ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE', '--android-entrypoint', 'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity', '--android-apptheme', '@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar', '--meta-data', 'com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713', '--presplash', '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/./images/loading.png', '--icon', '/home/seo/Desktop/APP/./images/icon.png', '--orientation', 'portrait', '--window', '--enable-androidx', '--copy-libs', '--depend', "'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.4.0'", '--arch', 'arm64-v8a', '--arch', 'armeabi-v7a', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/seo/Desktop/APP/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']

# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/seo:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2812,unix/seo:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2812'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'gnome-keyring'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/seo/Desktop/APP'
#     LOGNAME = 'seo'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'wayland'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '2812'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.OD6BJ2'
#     HOME = '/home/seo'
#     USERNAME = 'seo'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'

#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'

#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6800'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/106a7e88_f4e2_4f71_a0af_df2f59eb382d'
#     GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY = ':1'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'seo'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.148'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=3f19386d594c848fbecbb08b65d31412'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'

#     PATH = '/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/seo/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/seo/.local/bin/'

#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=3f19386d594c848fbecbb08b65d31412'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/seo/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/seo/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '33'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Thanks very much

Comment: So sorry my bad english. I re edit again i think it is now ok. It clearly tells us the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

```
android.meta_data = 'com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID = ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713'
```

In above vode there are `''` signs that causes this error.

The right code is

```
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
```

Thanks